# mysql jdbc communicationexception

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc

I have BLManager class that first open connection and called Data manager class to get data from database and return list of VO containing that data.

After completing all calculation in BL manager i call the method that commit transaction and close the connection.

This is the flow that i follow for opening and closing database connection. Today i face some strange exception described as follow

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: The driver was unable to create a connection due to an inability to establish the client portion of a socket.

This is usually caused by a limit on the number of sockets imposed by the operating system. This limit is usually configurable. 

For Unix-based platforms, see the manual page for the 'ulimit' command. Kernel or system reconfiguration may also be required.

For Windows-based platforms, see Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 196271 (Q196271).
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1070)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:298)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at com.cc.jas.datamanager.util.db.DBManager.getConnection(DBManager.java:83)
 at com.cc.jas.blmanager.base.BaseBLManager.startTransaction(BaseBLManager.java:252)
 at com.cc.jas.blmanager.system.systemconfig.SystemConfigBLManager.getConfigMap(SystemConfigBLManager.java:82)
 at com.cc.jas.delegate.system.systemconfig.SystemConfigBusinessDelegate.getConfigMap(SystemConfigBusinessDelegate.java:39)
 at com.cc.jas.common.cache.SystemConfigCacheManager.reloadCache(SystemConfigCacheManager.java:120)
 at com.cc.jas.common.cache.SystemConfigCacheManager.getParameterValue(SystemConfigCacheManager.java:53)
 at com.cc.jas.model.base.BaseReportVO.getDisplayDate(BaseReportVO.java:116)
 at com.cc.jas.model.account.rvo.AccountItemReportVO.getDateString(AccountItemReportVO.java:111)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1773)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1132)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:686)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:715)
 at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:290)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:115)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:100)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:787)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:751)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1422)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:879)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:801)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:536)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:63)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:209)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2027)
```

What this exception says and what is solution for that ?

Comment: Think this might help as it is the only likely answer this,avalailable http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect

This says that the `ip:port` you are trying to bind with process is already binded with some other process.

Answer (score 0):

try doing `ping 127.0.0.1` to see if tcp/ip is working or not.then use `netstat -a` to see the open ports and sockets.